# How to catch `CParserError` when reading a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to read a list of CSVs into a dataframe. However, I'm having trouble catching an error that occurs when the file has header rows that do not match the data itself (i.e. metadata or additional blank rows). This error is a 'CParserError' (see my error messages at the bottom).

My current solution is to use a try-except statement, with

```
try:
    #read file
except CParserError:
    #give me an error message
```

However, this fails with the below error:

```
NameError: name 'CParserError' is not defined
```

My code is below. As you can see I think I require multiple except statements to catch the various errors. The first should check that the default encoding types work (the files will never be anything other than utf-8 or latin-1). If there are header rows, pd.read_csv gives a 'CParserError' message (see below) which I need to catch. Then, if there are any other miscellaneous issues I want to catch those too.

Any solutions welcome, that ideally would explain why CParserError isn't right, or if the try-except logic could be amended to avoid the reliance on this.

Thanks.

```
files_list = glob.glob('*.csv*')     #get all csvs
files_dict = {}           
for file in files_list:
    try:
        files_dict[file] = pd.read_csv('DFA_me_week27.csv', encoding='utf-8').read() 
    except UnicodeDecodeError:    
        files_dict[file] = pd.read_csv('DFA_me_week27.csv', encoding='Latin-1').read()
    except CParserError:
        print(file, 'failed: check for header rows')
    except:
        print(file, 'failed: some other error occurred')
```

The error message when trying to parse a CSV file with headers:

```
CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e454c053d675> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_csv('DFA_me_week27.csv')

C:\Users\john.lwli\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, na_fvalues, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    463                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    464 
--> 465         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    466 
    467     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Users\john.lwli\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    249         return parser
    250 
--> 251     return parser.read()
    252 
    253 _parser_defaults = {

C:\Users\john.lwli\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
    708                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
    709 
--> 710         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    711 
    712         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

C:\Users\john.lwli\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1157 
   1158         try:
-> 1159             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1160         except StopIteration:
   1161             if nrows is None:

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7403)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:7643)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8260)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:8134)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:20720)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 12, saw 12
```

Comment: Why not just skip the header?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this? I'm not sure it would be an easy task, given that sometimes the headers are in different formats. e.g. sometimes it'll be 12 lines and 2 columns worth of header rows; other times it will be just one row.

Comment: What do you mean by *12 lines and 2 columns worth of header rows*?  You could also `error_bad_lines=False` but that would ignore all bad   lines

Comment: let's say my valuable data is a 12x5000 table. There could be metadata at the top of the file saying    report_id = 1234; user_id = 1234; date = 6/7 etc. etc. so there are some number of rows which are not useful. The point is, is that this number of rows is not constant so I can't simply say _'skip **n** rows'_, if that's your suggestion.

Comment: If you want to catch a `CParserError` use  `except pd.parser.CParserError:`

Comment: I just tried the 'error_bad_lines' idea and it read the metadata, and didn't read the main file... although there is a =Warn parameter which could work...

Comment: If you want to catch CParserErrors then use the code above, what do you want to do if the file cannot be parsed because of a `CParserError`?

Comment: pd.parser.CParserError solved my issues, thanks

Answer (score 6):

I hate to state the obvious, but...

```
from pandas.parser import CParserError
```

---

FutureWarning: The pandas.parser module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use the following instead

```
import from the pandas.io.parser
```

Answer (score 1):

I use 

`from pandas.parser import CParserError`

And I got 

`FutureWarning: The pandas.parser module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please import from the pandas.io.parser instead`

So 

`from pandas.io.parser import CParserError`

is recommended.

I'm using Python 3.6, and my pandas version is 0.20.3

---

However, when I use `from pandas.io.parser import CParserError` I got 

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io.parser'`

Comment: Same here, none of these answers work.
Edit: This works: `except pd.parser.CParserError:`

Answer (score 0):

If your have import pandas as pd, you can except the error like this (pandas 0.19):

`except pd.parser.CParserError:`

Comment: Error i was having "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 22, saw 8"