# Pandas Read_CSV Handle Empty Files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am looping through a directory with CSV files, reading them using pandas' read_csv.

Some of these files will be empty (only headers), so i get the following error:

> CParserError: Passed header=1 but only 1 lines in file

Though i am sure there is a better way, my first instinct is to handle the error, as follows:

```
try:
    v = pd.read_csv(strPath, header = 1)
except CParserError:
    return
```

But this causes the following error:

> NameError: name 'CParserError' is not defined

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this `data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)` ??

Comment: header = 1 is necessary? In onother data is header in second row of csv?

Comment: Import fix - `from pandas.parser import CParserError`

Comment: import 
`from pandas.parser import CParserError`

Comment: might be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245264/how-to-catch-cparsererror-when-reading-a-csv-file